# Dynamically assign CSS class to another class

Tags: php, css

Is it possible to assign properties of one CSS class to another class? If it can not be done with CSS, I can use server-side scripting to pass variables.

For example, if I have a list of classes from .myclass1 to .myclass20 and I know that for user7 I need to replace .myDefault with myClass7, how can I do that?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what needed to be done. I prefer doing that before I start writing code. It seems LESS is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all properties in a class to be inherited by another class in CSS.

Not for both classes to be applied on an object dynamically by JS.

That can't be done directly with CSS and a JS approach would consume quite a bit of time for you to implement.

Best choice is for you to look into [less css](http://lesscss.org/).

It does what you want, either server side or clientside.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you could this code:

```
$('.myDefault').addClass('myClass7');
$('.myClass7').removeClass('myDefault');
```

Comment: I need to keep the class as is in the document, but replace the properties with the properties from another one.

Comment: I looked into it, and it seems that you should try LESS JS as stated by Mihai

Comment: Yes, I am leaning towards using LESS too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but if you want a mix of settings you can use multiple classes:

```
bigFont{
  font-size:150%;
}
errorBox{
  border:4px dashed red;
}
typMessage{
  padding:2px;
  margin:1px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}


<div class="typMessage">Hello World</div>
```

by adding the "errorBox" and/or "bigFont" class to the element it will "merge" the CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to swap classes without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/mrKHB/

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="big one sans phone">Hello world and </div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {background:blue;color:#fff}
.two {background:yellow;color:#000}
.sans {font-family:sans-serif}
.big {font-size:24px}
.phone:after {content:"phone!"}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = (function(){
this.className = this.className.replace(/\bone\b/,"two");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to handle this for you.
Just replace e.g.

```
<div class='myDefault'></div>
```

with

```
// you should have that info stored somewhere anyway :)
$userClass = 'myClass7';

// now just echo out the right class for the user
<div class="<?php echo $userClass ?>"></div>
```